# How to rename the create-react-app top level folder without conflict?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I've seen similar questions before, but the use cases seem to be renaming the app to another lowercase name or it never goes into potential problems that will occur if the folder being uppercase disrupts it other than going against npm conventions.

*My ReactJS app is designed just to be a front-end application with client side routing, I don't plan on publishing it on to npm, but I will deploy it on a production level with potentially different types of web servers hosting it.*

**My method for renaming:**

I want my react app to be placed in a folder called MyReactApp.

1. Run npx cra. NPM doesn't allow uppercases: `npx create-react-app MyReactApp`
2. So I run: `npx create-react-app my-react-app`
3. My app now sits on a folder called `my-react-app/src/index.js` with a package name of `my-react-app`
4. Now, can I simply go ahead and change only the top level folder name like: `my-react-app/src/index.js` to `MyReactAppDiffName/src/index.js`.

By doing it this way, am I potentially messing up dependency structures or introducing problems later on?

*I'm currently in the early stages of my app after renaming it like this and there doesn't seem to be a problem yet. Sorry, I don't know if I'm simply overthinking the naming restriction and/or just assuming the top level folder is included under the package .*

Also, I have seen this link, but I'm not sure if it's solely talking about the package name:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3914#issuecomment-24878907

> 1. URL paths and couch doc ids are case sensitive.
> 2. The file systems on most unixes are case sensitive.
> 3. Human brains are mostly case INsensitive.

and this link: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2165#issuecomment-301627339

Comment: Once you're building the app in order to put it on a server, the project name doesn't matter anyway. It'll just be a bunch of files inside the build folder, not containing any reference to the project name afaik. Which means I don't see the need to rename the project in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisG That's fair. I was just wondering because the project I am contributing to has an existing repository with the parent folder being camel cased following their guidelines and I needed to add the react-app at the root. I just wanted to double check. Thanks!